# Time Delay in loop with Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have some loop function for the game, this loop for open the 9 box, here the code

```
function random_item_2(coinsx)
{
    var listItem:Array = new Array();
    for (var i:uint=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        listItem.push(i);
    }
    ItemLeft = 0;
    for (var x:uint=0; x<boardWidth; x++)
    {
        for (var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight; y++)
        {
            var thisItem:FirstBox = new FirstBox();
            thisItem.x = x * IcardHorizontalSpacing + IboardOffsetX;
            thisItem.y = y * IcardVerticalSpacing + IboardOffsetY;
            var r:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * listItem.length);
            thisItem.cardface = listItem[r];
            listItem.splice(r,1);
            thisItem.gotoAndStop(thisItem.cardface+2);
            var itemFound = this.foundItem(thisItem.cardface);
            if (itemFound == 50 || itemFound == 100 || itemFound == 250 || itemFound == 500 || itemFound == 1000)
            {
                var itemC = Number(coinsx) + Number(itemFound);
                coinsx = itemC;
                update_coins(Number(coinsx));
                info_coinstext(String(coinsx));
                trace('Gold Coins Found > '+itemFound);
            }else if(itemFound!='Kosong'){
                updateItem(itemFound);
                trace('Item Found > '+itemFound);
            }
            addChild(thisItem);
            ItemLeft++;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is, 9 box open in one time, not one by one, i want to box open the box one by one, after the first box opened so the next box will open, here for some algo that i wanted

```
open the first box
delay 5 sec
open the second box
delay for 5 sec
```

how i can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the delay in your for loop you should write something like this:

```
function random_item_2(coinsx)
{
    var listItem:Array = new Array();
    for (var i:uint=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        listItem.push(i);
    }
    ItemLeft = 0;

    const DELAY:int = 5000;

    for (var x:uint=0; x<boardWidth; x++)
    {
        for (var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight; y++)
        {
            setTimeout(addItem, (x*boardHeight+y)*DELAY, x, y);
        }
    }
}

function addItem(x:uint, y:uint) : void
{
    var thisItem:FirstBox = new FirstBox();
    thisItem.x = x * IcardHorizontalSpacing + IboardOffsetX;
    thisItem.y = y * IcardVerticalSpacing + IboardOffsetY;

    var r:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * listItem.length);

    thisItem.cardface = listItem[r];
    listItem.splice(r,1);
    thisItem.gotoAndStop(thisItem.cardface+2);

    var itemFound = this.foundItem(thisItem.cardface);

    if(itemFound == 50 || itemFound == 100 || itemFound == 250 || itemFound == 500 || itemFound == 1000)
    {
        var itemC = Number(coinsx) + Number(itemFound);
        coinsx = itemC;
        update_coins(Number(coinsx));
        info_coinstext(String(coinsx));
        trace('Gold Coins Found > '+itemFound);
    }
    else if(itemFound!='Kosong')
    {
        updateItem(itemFound);
        trace('Item Found > '+itemFound);
    }

    addChild(thisItem);
    ItemLeft++;
}
```

By increasing the delay every time you set the timeout, the function will be called later.

Comment: thanks @rvmook, thats great, now the code run with delay to open the box, but openen box not one by one, sometimes 3 box opened in one time, if you don't mind how could that be ? when i use  `for (var y:uint=boardHeight; y<1; y++)` the box not opened at all, but if i changes to `for (var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight; y++)` the box is opened but like i said before some box stil opened in one time, any advise ?

Comment: ah sorry, that was a typo in my code. (Didn't really test it thoroughly. Here's the right equation is `(x*boardHeight+y)*DELAY`. (it's also updated in the answer)

Comment: np, but like @pranav-hosangadi and @ThomasM pointed out. Using a `Timer` is considered better practice. So next time try to work around the for loop setTimeOut setup.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a couple of options.

You could use setTimeout to delay a function call:

```
setTimeout(functionToExecuteAfterDelay, 2000)
```

OR

You could use the Timer Class in as3 to execute functions on set periods of time.

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000,9); //Will tick 9 times, each after 5000 milliseconds
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,someFunction);
myTimer.start();
function someFunction(event:TimerEvent) {
    //do your openingstuff here
}
```

Personally, I'd take option 2. Also, remove the TimerEvent listener after you're done with it.

Comment: thanks @ThomasM, It work fine, but when i put this on the loop it seem doesn't work, all box stil open in one time, have you idea hoe to put that inside `for` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of `setInterval`

```
var interval:int=0;
var nextBoxToOpen:int=0;
var maxBoxes:int = 9;

function openBox(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //code to open box;
    nextBoxToOpen++;
    if(nextBoxToOpen >= maxBoxes) {
        nextBoxToOpen=0;
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}

function startOpen():void {
    interval = setInterval(openBox, 5000);
}
```

OR, in AS3 you could use a Timer

```
var tmr:Timer = new Timer(5000, 9); //Interval = 5000 ms, Number of ticks = 9
tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, openBox);
tmr.start();
function openBox():void {
    var boxToOpen = tmr.currentCount;
    //code to open box;
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, but the box has their own position, according stage width. how can i re position them whit out `for`, some how the box have a different position for each other of them

Comment: Whatever code you use to reposition, remove the for which loops over the box numbers and use the `nextBoxToOpen` or `boxToOpen` variable instead of that index.